# Formatting the automated email send from google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have been looking all over the web and could not find a way to format the email sent from a Google spreadsheet application. I have tried using inline html elements, but the API is escaping them and sending them as plain text in the email. Does anyone have an idea how to format the text?

Comment: Are you using [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script)? Check out [MailApp Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app), specifically [sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app?hl=en#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)) – options: htmlBody

Comment: I have tried:"var options = {options:"htmlBody"}" and then "sendEmail(email,subject,message,options)" but still ignores it. How do I specify the options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following code:

```
...
var options = {
  htmlBody: '<b><i>TEST</i></b>'
};
MailApp.sendEmail('someone@domain.ext', 'TEST', 'TEST', options);
...
```